# Windows 10 all USB sticks of same type write-protected. How to fix?

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive, write-protect

I wanted to create a Windows 10 boot stick, but pulled out the stick too early. Now every USB stick of this type is write-protected and I can't find a way to remove this write-protection.

For reference, this is a screenshot of the properties:

[image]

Following are the steps I tried to remove the write-protection:

1. Right click -> Format -> disk is write protected:

[image]

2. Use `diskpart` to clear read-only attributes:

[image]

3. Use `diskpart` to `clean` the stick:

[image]

4. Run `CHKDK /F /R` on the stick:

[image]

5. Format via disk management:

[image]

6. Add registry key:

[image]

As you can see, everything failed. If it was just one stick, I'd throw it away, but it is every stick of the same type/manufacturer.

I don't care about the data on these sticks. I just want them to be useable again. **What else can I do?**

---

EDIT:

Picture of registry folder structure

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing and reinstalling the appropriate driver(s)?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? [Cold boot - shut down, wait 30s (if it's a desktop without built-in battery, unplug from the mains & press the boot button a few times to dump remaining capacitor power, then re-plug), boot up.]

Comment: I have now tried with uninstalling USB drivers as well as doing a cold boot. Both failed as well

Comment: Check the sticks in another machine.

Comment: @Tetsujin also write protected on other devices

Answer (score 0):

Using Device manager with one usb plugged in find the device ID of that specific usb drive "VID_0000&PID_0000". Copy this down and then open regedit and go to:

> "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB" and find that specific VID,

then delete that specific key, reboot and see if it works now.

you may have to do this for the keys below also

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet001\Enum\USB
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet002\Enum\USB

Comment: Actually I can't even delete the keys. I tried to delete the "folder" for this device and it fails. Then I tried to access the sub folders "Properties" (picture in question) and I don't have access, even as admin.